# .Net SMTP Queue

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, email, smtp

Has anyone seen a .net email queue?

I want to be able to specify the SMTP server to send via, report problems and retry emails if necessary or requested.

Ideally I'd like something open source.

Comment: Hi Fran - what solution did you end up with here please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout System.Net.Mail, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1fb84h.aspx.  In particular you want to look at MailMessage and SmtpClient.

EDIT

```
 // Invokes the SendEmail method on another thread.
 // Read MSDN on catching exception on completion and then wait a bit and send again.
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendEmail());
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm quite familier with sending emails, but I want to be able to pass of the sending of an email to another service so that the user doesn't have to wait for the email to be sent and errors don't stop the main thread.

Comment: How about sending on a another using TPL, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx.  See my edit on creating a Task on another thread.

Comment: That looks more like it! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you are using .NET on Windows you can use the IIS SMTP service. Use SmtpClient and set the delivery method to pickup directory. Under this mode the SmtpClient will write to the SMTP pickup folder (something like c:\inetpub\smtp_root\pickup) instead of trying to deliver the mail itself. That folder is the queue of messages, and SMTP service will handle delivery, retry, and NDR's, etc. Much better than trying to write it yourself.

Comment: Is this *still* the best way to accomplish this? This approach requires IIS6 be installed on a server, and it's been flaky lately, SMTP service dies after patches, etc.